# Window phone 8 picture gallery design guidelines

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i am designing a application for photos for which i have to display around 40 photos in the gallery, what are the basic guidelines designing a photo gallery what should i used,

- image gallery should be vertical or horizontal...?
- if horizontal then how many image should i display while scrolling down..?
- can i use panorama , pivot controls or paging for displaying photos.
- can you people specify any reference for photo gallery for window phone from where i can  take some idea
- which control i should use for image gallery.

Comment: If you're unsure how to design an app, then use one of the built-in apps as a starting point eg. Photos app

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Photos app OR Genius Scan Application in the marketplace for reference. Genius scan would be a better third part option in front of you.